# Can I make a dua from Allah to forgive the prophet?

Tags: dua

I was asking for forgiveness when I said oh Allah forgive Muhammad, is this wrong or is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

As Muslims, we believe that the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) is the best of creation and is free from any sins. Therefore, there is no need to make a dua for his forgiveness, as he is already forgiven by Allah.

In the Qur'an, Allah addresses the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) in Surah Al-Ahzab (33:56):

إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَمَلَائِكَتَهُ يُصَلُّونَ عَلَى النَّبِيِّ ۚ يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا صَلُّوا عَلَيْهِ وَسَلِّمُوا تَسْلِيمًا

"Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [Allah to grant him] peace."

This verse shows that Allah and His angels send blessings upon the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him). As believers, we are also encouraged to send blessings and peace upon him.

In a hadith narrated by Anas ibn Malik (may Allah be pleased with him), the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said, "None of you will have faith till he loves me more than his father, his children, and all mankind." (Sahih al-Bukhari 15)

This hadith emphasizes the importance of loving and respecting the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) as a fundamental part of our faith.

Therefore, instead of making a dua for the forgiveness of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), it is more appropriate to send blessings and peace upon him, as instructed by Allah in the Qur'an.

May Allah bless and grant peace to the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) and may we all strive to follow his example.